# Selenium RemoteWebDriver I/O Exception java.net.NoRouteToHostException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I work on a Mac to write test using Java. I have a Selenium Grid (Hub) on a Linux, I start it successfully by this command:

```
java -jar /bin/selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role hub -port 4444 &
```

I have a VM Windows, then I register it as a Selenium Node by this command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.50.34:4444/grid/register/
```

I see that on Selenium Grid said: Registered a node http://*VMWindowsIP*, but then it said:

```
17:35:24.331 INFO - Nodes should register to http://10.0.50.34:4444/grid/register/
17:35:24.331 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
17:43:11.211 INFO - Registered a node http://*VMWindowsIP*:5555
17:43:19.307 INFO - I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when processing request to {}->http://*VMWindowsIP*:5555: No route to host
```

I don't know what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that my node was behind a VPC, so I changed the network configuration and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try these

Register Hub

```
java -jar /bin/selenium-server/selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

Register Node

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://10.0.50.34:4444/grid/register -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\IEDriverServer.exe  -host
```

Comment: Register driver capabilities according to your specifications. I mean whether ur script needs to be executed in IE, Chrome,Safari

Comment: I tried, then I got this error:
`10:24:53.620 INFO - Registered a node http://:5555`
`10:25:03.625 INFO - Marking the node http://:5555 as down: cannot reach the node for 2 tries`
`10:26:03.646 INFO - Unregistering the node http://:5555 because it's been down for 60021 milliseconds`

This time I don't see IP of the registered node

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub 10.24.53.620:4444/grid/register -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\IEDriverServer.exe -host 10.24.53.(Your Node IP address)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved this problem, turned out its not because of the script, it was VPC.